# How can we write test cases for Alert or pop up in testcafe?

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

We have various popups on our website which are used for validation.
How can we write test cases in Testcafe for alerts/popups?

Not able to inspect alert and hence not able to get the id.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [setNativeDialogHandler](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/testcontroller/setnativedialoghandler.html) method to handle alert windows.

Its API and examples are available in the [corresponding help topic](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/testcontroller/setnativedialoghandler.html).